# JSON body for POST request

Tags: json, go, go-http

I am building a body for a POST request

```
relativeurl := "this-is-a-test-url"

postBody := fmt.Sprintf("{\"requests\": [{\"httpMethod\": \"GET\",\"relativeUrl\": \"%s\"}]}", relativeurl)
```

When I do a `fmt.Println` of `postBody`, I see:

```
{
"requests": [
    {
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "relativeUrl": "this-is-a-test-url"}]}
```

but the url is expecting a JSON:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "relativeUrl": "this-is-a-test-url"
        }
]
}
```

Is the way I build the post body wrong?

Comment: Check this out https://yourbasic.org/golang/json-example/

Comment: Use the [json](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I see twice the same valid json payloads -- the only difference is in the formatting. The only possible issue I see is the lack of json escaping on the `relativeUrl` value. Were you looking for something more ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to mention another way to correctly escape a JSON string :

```golang
// call the json serializer just on the string value :
escaped, _ := json.Marshal(relativeUrl)
// the 'escaped' value already contains its enclosing '"', no need to repeat them here :
body := fmt.Sprintf("{\"requests\": [{\"httpMethod\": \"GET\",\"relativeUrl\": %s}]}", escaped)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/WaT-RCnDQuK

Answer (score 1):

Your two JSON output examples are both valid and functionally equivalent. White space is not significant in JSON. See the following at [JSON.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

> Whitespace can be inserted between any pair of tokens.

You can test and format your JSON easily using `encoding/json` or an online JSON parser.

However, the approach you are using is prone to error since your URL needs to be properly escaped. For example, if your URL has a double quote, `"`, in it, your code will produce invalid JSON.

In Go, it's much better to create some structs to encode. For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type RequestBody struct {
    Requests []Request `json:"requests"`
}

type Request struct {
    HTTPMethod  string `json:"httpMethod"`
    RelativeURL string `json:"relativeUrl"`
}

func main() {
    body := RequestBody{
        Requests: []Request{{
            HTTPMethod:  "GET",
            RelativeURL: "this-is-a-test-url",
        }},
    }

    bytes, err := json.MarshalIndent(body, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(bytes))
}
```

Here's a running example:

https://play.golang.org/p/c2iU6blG3Rg

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) package to handle json inputs and outputs. Use [json.Unmarshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal) function to convert json to golang structure and use [json.Marshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal) function to convert golang structure to json.